# windows_zipfile Chef resource failing due to 'rubyzip' gem file download

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

We are facing a situation, where end users Windows VM does not have internet connectivity, but only have access to file store.

We are using [`windows_zipfile`](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/windows#windows_zipfile) resource in one of our recipe. So cookbook execution failed in Windows cookbook, due to the reason that, it is not able to download `rubyzip` from "rubygems.org" site.

We are thinking of solving the issue in either of these two ways,

1. Replace the `windows_zipfile` code with `powershell_script` and implement the code using Powershell commands
2. Load the `rubyzip` gem and its dependency in file store and install the gems before calling `windows_zipfile` resource.

Please provide suggestions to handle the scenario. Also let me know, is there any other way to solve the issue.

Comment: Voting to close, not a good fit for SO, both choices are valid, along with creating an internal gem repository or using a proxy and a white list to give servers an internet access, choosing one is a mater of opinion and what fit best your team/company usage is up to you, not to recommendations...

Comment: FWIW at $COMPANY we use the last one, proxy with a restricted white list the servers can access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install a `chef_gem` from a local path, after downloading it from a source inside your network (just replace the URL of https://rubygems.org):

```rb
{"httpclient" => "2.7.1", "rubyzip" => "1.1.7"}.each do |gem,version|
  filename = "#{gem}-#{version}.gem"
  remote_file File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], filename) do
    source "https://rubygems.org/downloads/#{filename}"
  end

  chef_gem gem do
    source File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], filename)
    version version
  end
end
```

As the Gem is used by Chef's ruby, make sure to use the [chef_gem](https://docs.chef.io/resource_chef_gem.html) resource.